# Getting image slider to have a maximum number of images in view and hide the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to add onto an image slider I made a long time ago. I used to only have four thumbnail images under my large image. I now want more than four. I want the excess images to hide until I select the next arrow. I'm not sure of how to get the excess images show. I'm sure I have to set a max limit to show at once, but I'm not sure of where to add it. I want the set of thumbnail images to rotate by 4.

I created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1gLgg7uq/

I added in

```
//Thumb controls
$('.thumbcontrols li').click(function () {
    var
    //Slideshow
    sshow = $(this).closest('.slideshow'),
        //Increment
        incr = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? -1 : 1,
        //Current Index
        currentIndx = sshow.find('.big li').index(sshow.find('.big li:visible')),
        //Final Index
        finalIndx = currentIndx + incr;

    //Check ranges
    finalIndx = (finalIndx >= 4) ? 0 : ((finalIndx < 0) ? 3 : finalIndx);

    //Now trigger click event on respective image in nav
    sshow.find('.thumb li:eq(' + finalIndx + ')').trigger('click');
});
$('#bxslider-horizontal .bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    infiniteLoop: false,
    pager: false,
    slideWidth: 200,
    maxSlides: 4,
    minSlides: 2,
    slideMargin: 10
});
```

I'm attempting to modify code that I found a long time ago and I have minimal experience with Java Script. I understand the basics of show and hide, but I am not sure how to apply it to what I am trying to do. I'm sure I need some kind of minimum/maximum setting in place, but not sure how to configure that.

Does anyone have a suggestions of what I need to modify to get this to work or should I scratch the above code that I posted and try to do it a different way?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/7vxjpeyj/

i made a flex in the list of items, and I change part of this html as well.

```
 <ul class='thumb' id="bxslider-horizontal">
     <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/" />
     </li>
     ....


#bxslider-horizontal{
    display: flex;       
    width: 530px;

    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
 #bxslider-horizontal li{
    flex: 1; 
 }


#bxslider-horizontal li img{
    width:100%
}
```

**NOTE** the flex are prefixes in the fiddler.

The javascript need know that have a variable number of elements. I don´t touch your code only update the number

```
numImages = sshow.find('.thumb li').length;
finalIndx = (finalIndx >= numImages) ? 0 : ( (finalIndx < 0) ? (numImages-1) : finalIndx);
```

Comment: I'm looking for the thumbnails to act in a carousel manner. So that I can have 4 thumbnail images, but if there are 8 images, the next/previous button in the thumbnail part will show the next set of images... Something like this... http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/28/

Comment: There's not a way to do that with my existing code?